# Using a Network Attached Storage (NAS) for developing

Tags: php, network-storage

I was enjoining about getting a `Network Attached Storage (NAS)` so that I can work on `dev` sites from both my desktop and my laptop without duplicating files and always having the most current file (just in case I forget to save). My question is if I put sites on there that uses php, would I be able to run the sites off of the `NAS` as I would with `MAMP` / `WAMP`? Or would I still need something else to make that work?

Comment: Depends on you NAS. Which Model are you using?

Comment: Using Apache's Virtual Hosts feature should be able to do that. However, be careful about putting databases in a shared location and running 2 MySQL servers at the same time. They wont talk and they will both think they have complete control. _There be dragons_

Comment: A better solution would be a source management tool like GIT

Comment: Read [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#windrivemap) - might help. (Tho I think that I may have missed the point of the question...)

Comment: @user2959229 Virtual Hosts are a much better solution that Alias's

Comment: I was thinking about using Western Digital My Cloud. I won't be using both computers at once,  just sometimes I like to use my laptop in the living room and other times I use my desktop in my office.

Comment: What do you mean alias's?

Answer (score 2):

The point of a NAS is to share files over a network. This is usually done via Windows File & Print Sharing (aka Samba aka SMB) which is supported on most platforms.

Some NAS devices might allow you to run a web server (particularly if you can install custom firmware), but it is a poor choice of platform to run anything remotely complex in terms of web server stacks.

You can certainly store your development files on a NAS, and then access them from webservers running in both your development environments.

… but that said, I'd look at using version control software (Git would be my preference), keeping your repository on the NAS and getting into the habit of saving, committing and pushing. It makes things more manageable in the long run. (You could also use a service like Bitbucket or Github and dispense with the local NAS entirely).

You could also go a step further and run a server with CI software on it that monitors your repository and automatically pulls updates from it, runs your automated tests, and then updates a local test server.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you use windows(it's easier to do it in mac i think) with wamp what you can do is mount a network drive to w:\ let's say. Then create a virtual host that points to a folder in W:\ drive.

With mac all you need to do is mount the remote folder share to your mamp directory and all should work as you want.

Though personally I think this is a terrible idea and would much rather suggest you to use a VCS(version control system) to share code between multiple places. Lots of them are designed with this problem in mind. And it provides nice history about your code at the same time. If you want to do some research look at GIT(the most popular, currently) bitbucket has free private repositories. you can look into what a VCS can do here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control